# Передать значения переменных в цикле php

Tags: php, битрикс, foreach

Добрый вечер. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать.
Есть массив:
$prods

```
Array
(
[21020] => 1050
[19671] => 1000
)
```

И 
цикл

```
$basketItem->setFields(array(
'PRODUCT_ID' => '', 
'CUSTOM_PRICE' => 'Y',
'PRICE' => '',
));
```

Не могу понять как передать значения из массива в $basketItem.

Где PRODUCT_ID это 17215 и 21020
а 
PRICE это 3200 и 1050 соответственно.

Comment: А где собственно цикл? И какого действия вы ожидаете? С чем работаете, какой ожидаемый результат?

Comment: `foreach($prods as $k=>$v)$basketItem->setFields(['PRODUCT_ID'=>$k, 'PRICE'=>$v]);`

Answer (score 0):

```
PRODUCT_ID => array_keys($prod)
```

А для второго параметра

```
PRICE => array_values($prod)
```

Запишет в данные параметры массивы ключей (0 => 17215 и т.д.) и значений (0 => 3200 и т.д.)

Соответвенно для получения значений будете писать (при получении данного массива) `$array['PRODUCT_ID'][$i]` в цикле. И так же будет выбираться и второе значение